# financequotes API returning null values

Tags: java, api, null, finance

I have downloaded an API called "financequotes" for Java (Link: http://financequotes-api.com/) and have attempted to use it for a project. It has been imported into my class path and all the methods run, however when I ask for a stocks details

```
Stock s = new Stock("INTC");
s.print();
```

I am given back all the details which should have been obtained online as null including name, currency, quote, etc.

Why is this?

**ALTERNATIVELY - Could you suggest another finance API which is relatively simple to use to gather basic financial data?**

Thanks

Comment: Asking for suggestions on libraries, is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I know, that is why I am asking mainly for a solution to the problem on the library I have, as it seems ideal. I only ask for alternatives if the problem can't be solved :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of the API has answered - Here was the problem

The code doesn't have a request to Yahoo Finance yet. There's 2 alternative ways to fix this.

1. Request it through the YahooFinance static methods

   ```
   Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("INTC");
   stock.print();
   ```
2. Force a refresh of the stock's quote by using the getQuote(boolean refresh) method

   ```
   Stock stock = new Stock("INTC");
   stock.getQuote(true);
   stock.print();
   ```

This will automatically also load/refresh the statistics and dividend data.

Answer (score 0):

Intrinio provides a simple to use API for financial information. It looks like you are a Java user, there are packages on for [connecting via rest API](http://github.com/hhorton2/Intrinio-SDK) and for [connecting to real time prices via websocket](https://github.com/cerudite/IntrinioIEXRealtime).

The API is easy to use for stock prices, fundamentals, options, analyst estimates, etc. [This tutorial will](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/web_api) get you started, but here is an example in curl:

```
 curl "https://api.intrinio.com/prices?ticker=AAPL" -u "API_Password:API_Username"
```